# Android ExpandableListView not scrolling properly

Tags: android, listview, scroll

My `ExpandableListView` is not scrolling properly; 
i can only scroll the `ListView` when it's not moving, which is extremely annoying for quick navigation.
Once the scrolling is set in motion I cannot control it until it's not moving again.

I use `eventListView.expandGroup(0); eventListView.expandGroup(1); ...` to expand all the groups.

The xml is also nothing that special:

```
    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/event_list"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:paddingBottom="90dip"
        android:clipToPadding="false"/>
```

The `ListView` has an Adapter and a `OnChildClickListener` and that's pretty much it. I've searched everywhere but i cannot seem to find an answer, can anyone help?

The full xml code for that view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="fill_parent"
     android:id="@+id/timetable"
     android:background="@color/bg_white">

    <include android:id="@+id/placeholder_events"
         layout="@layout/placeholder_layout"/>

     <ExpandableListView
         android:id="@+id/event_list"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:paddingBottom="90dip"
         android:clipToPadding="false"/>

     <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="56dp"
         android:layout_height="56dp"
         android:src="@drawable/icon_left_arrow"
         android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
         android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
         android:id="@+id/timetable_previousWeek_button"
         android:elevation="1dp"
         android:background="@drawable/floating_action_button"/>

     <ImageButton
         android:layout_width="56dp"
         android:layout_height="56dp"
         android:src="@drawable/icon_right_arrow"
         android:layout_gravity="right|bottom"
         android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
         android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
         android:id="@+id/timetable_nextWeek_button"
         android:elevation="1dp"
         android:background="@drawable/floating_action_button"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

---

EDIT

For others experiencing this problem, i had a gesture listener for left-to-right swipes who was getting the focus when scrolling. So basically that listener screwed up the scrolling up and down.

Comment: kindly post your code so we will be able to point out the bug, some time this happernds when you use listivew, etc inside scrollview, if so let me know i will solve.

Comment: sure, thanks. seemed pretty standard xml to me, but you are right, you never know.

Comment: your code looks pretty good. do your listview not scrolling properly or  you want soft scrooling of listview, if so i'm posting my answer. once i was using listview inside scrolview then it was not moving at all, because it interrupt scrolview.

Comment: For others experiencing this problem, i had a gesture listener for left-to-right swipes who was getting the focus when scrolling. So basically that listener screwed up the scrolling up and down.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the softer flow (movement) of list view, the do something like.
in your adapter class "getChildView()" method, get the convertview obj like.

```
 public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TTLHolder holder;
        if (convertView != null) {
        holder = (TTLHolder) convertView.getTag();
        } else {
         convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
         holder = new TTLHolder();
         holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
         convertView.setTag(holder);
     }

     holder.title.setText(this.getObjects().get(groupPosition).getValue()
            .get(childPosition).getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

And the "getGroupView()" method

```
 public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
        View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TTDHolder holder;

        if (convertView != null) {
        holder = (TTDHolder)convertView.getTag();
        } else {
             convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

             holder = new TTDHolder();
             holder.title = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
             convertView.setTag(holder);
       }
       holder.title.setText(this.getObjects().get(groupPosition).getKey().getName());

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the well explained answer. using your examples the listview still behaves the same way however, too bad.